# emacs/bash ctrl key shortcuts in all linux desktop environment

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, desktop-environment, distributions

I love the emacs keyboard shortcuts like c-f c-b c-d c-p c-a c-k c-y etc. And I've found that in OSX these work pretty much everywhere because all the typical control keys are tied to the command(alt or M-) key instead of ctrl. However, I don't like being locked into a specific set of hardware and would really like to be using linux for my desktop environment.

Is there a linux desktop environment that allows this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

you can configure custom keybindigs with [xbindkeys](http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html) in any desktop environment